# Wrong marker.line.color and marker.line.width

Tags: r, plotly

I am having some trouble when plotting some data using plotly, and I would like some help to understand what I can be doing wrong/misunderstanding.

I want to plot points (markers) colored according to the Color column and with a border (marker line) of a certain width and color according to the Selected column. It works well in some datasets, but in others it doesn't. So perhaps I am misusing the feature.

Let's suppose this dataset, `test_dataset`:

| Dim_1 | Dim_2 | Color | Text_ID | Seq_type | Selected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.83541 | -19.608079 | AH4 | A | R | AH4 |
| 4.38106 | -2.295184 | AH4 | B | R | AH4 |
| 22.15493 | -2.272569 | AH4 | C | R | User selected |
| 21.85514 | -3.964437 | AH4 | D | R | User selected |
| 22.07936 | 8.677288 | AH2 | E | R | AH2 |
| 17.56850 | -4.638592 | AH4 | F | R | AH4 |
| 1.21 | -4.592 | AH1 | G | R | AH1 |
| 4.21 | -5.592 | AH3 | H | R | AH3 |
| 4.21 | -21.592 | AH5 | I | R | AH5 |

```
BORDER_symbol=c("circle", "star-diamond")
names(BORDER_symbol)=c("R", "G")
Ex_colors=c( "#00798c", "#9e51bd","#9D5568" ,"#d1495b","#DF7C52" ,"#050609" ,"#ff4d6d" )
names(Ex_colors)=c("AH1", "AH2", "AH3", "AH4", "AH5","User selected", "Counterpart")
Ex_width=c(rep(3, 5),5,1)
names(Ex_width)=names(Ex_colors)

plot_ly(
  data = test,
  x =  ~ Dim_1,
  y = ~ Dim_2,
  color = ~ Color,
  colors = Ex_colors,
  opacity = 0.7,
  text =  ~ Text_ID,
  key = ~ Text_ID,
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'markers',
  hovertemplate = paste('<b>%{text}</b>'),
  
  marker = list(
    size = 7,
    line= list(color=(Ex_colors[match(test$Selected, names(Ex_colors))]),
               width=( Ex_width[match(test$Selected, names(Ex_width))]))
    
  )
)
```

As you can see in the image below, the border (marker line) colors are wrong, e.g. the first point at the left has a pink border and it should be blue.

[image: As you can see in the image, the colors are wrong, e.g. the first point at the left has a pink border and it should be blue.]

Is there something I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help. My `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.2.2 Patched (2022-11-10 r83330)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.10.1 ggplot2_3.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.10          tidyr_1.3.0          shinyWidgets_0.7.6   digest_0.6.31        utf8_1.2.3           mime_0.12            R6_2.5.1             RSQLite_2.2.20       httr_1.4.4          
[10] pillar_1.8.1         rlang_1.0.6          lazyeval_0.2.2       scrypt_0.1.6         rstudioapi_0.14      data.table_1.14.6    jquerylib_0.1.4      blob_1.2.3           R.utils_2.12.2      
[19] R.oo_1.25.0          DT_0.27              shinyjs_2.1.0        htmlwidgets_1.6.1    bit_4.0.5            munsell_0.5.0        shiny_1.7.4          compiler_4.2.2       httpuv_1.6.8        
[28] pkgconfig_2.0.3      askpass_1.1          billboarder_0.4.0    htmltools_0.5.4      openssl_2.0.5        tidyselect_1.2.0     tibble_3.1.8         fansi_1.0.4          viridisLite_0.4.1   
[37] dplyr_1.1.0          withr_2.5.0          later_1.3.0          R.methodsS3_1.8.2    grid_4.2.2           jsonlite_1.8.4       xtable_1.8-4         gtable_0.3.1         lifecycle_1.0.3     
[46] DBI_1.1.3            magrittr_2.0.3       scales_1.2.1         cli_3.6.0            cachem_1.0.6         farver_2.1.1         promises_1.2.0.1     bslib_0.4.2          ellipsis_0.3.2      
[55] generics_0.1.3       vctrs_0.5.2          tools_4.2.2          bit64_4.0.5          glue_1.6.2           purrr_1.0.1          crosstalk_1.2.0      Peptides_2.4.4       yaml_2.3.7          
[64] fastmap_1.1.0        colorspace_2.1-0     shinymanager_1.0.410 bigassertr_0.1.6     shinydashboard_0.7.2 memoise_2.0.1        sass_0.4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `color` for both the points and outer border of the points in the `marker` argument and with `line` like this:

```r
library(plotly)
plot_ly(
  data = test,
  x =  ~ Dim_1,
  y = ~ Dim_2,
  opacity = 0.7,
  text =  ~ Text_ID,
  key = ~ Text_ID,
  color = ~Color,
  colors = ~Ex_colors,
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'markers',
  hovertemplate = paste('<b>%{text}</b>'),
  marker = list(color = ~Color, size = 7, 
                line = list(color = Ex_colors, 
                            width=(Ex_width[match(test$Selected, names(Ex_width))]))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data used:

```
test = read.table(text = "Dim_1 Dim_2   Color   Text_ID Seq_type    Selected
10.83541    -19.608079  AH4 A   R   AH4
4.38106 -2.295184   AH4 B   R   AH4
22.15493    -2.272569   AH4 C   R   User_selected
21.85514    -3.964437   AH4 D   R   User_selected
22.07936    8.677288    AH2 E   R   AH2
17.56850    -4.638592   AH4 F   R   AH4
1.21    -4.592  AH1 G   R   AH1
4.21    -5.592  AH3 H   R   AH3
4.21    -21.592 AH5 I   R   AH5
", header =TRUE)
```